# javascript - how to check if exists child object value of key in object?

Tags: javascript

```
{
    "cd": {},
    "person": {},
    "p2": {
        "foo1": {},
        "foo2": {}
    }
}
```

`"cd"` doesn't have child object (empty object).
`"p2"` has child object. 
how to check if exists child object value?

Comment: Do you want to check the existence of a specific property of whether it has any properties at all?

Comment: @FelixKling i want to check any properties at all using for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hasChild(obj){
  return !!Object.keys(obj).length;
}
var obj = {
    "cd": {},
    "person": {},
    "p2": {
        "foo1": {},
        "foo2": {}
    }
};
console.log(hasChild(obj.cd));
console.log(hasChild(obj.p2));
```

Answer (score 2):

For specific child name you can try this:

```
var object = {
    "cd": {},
    "person": {},
    "p2": {
        "foo1": {},
        "foo2": {}
    }
}

if (object.cd.hasOwnProperty("childName")) {
// Do some stuff here
}
```

if you are looking for any child into the object you can try this

```
const objectToCheckIfHasChildren = object.cd;
const children = Object.keys(objectToCheckIfHasChildren);

if (children.length > 0) {
  // then children has at least one child
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that'll handle `null` and `undefined` as well.

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (const _ in obj) return false;
  return true;
}
```

You can add a `.hasOwnProperty()` check if you're worried about inherited, enumerable properties.

So an empty object, `null` and `undefined` will return `true` (being empty), otherwise `false` is returned.